# Existence of matrix with certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

If F is a field, n a positive integer,
c(x) in F[x] a polynomial of degree n,
and m(x) is in F[x] such that m(x) divides c(x) and
if p(x) in F[x] is an irreducible factor of c(x), then p(x) divides m(x),

Is it true that there exists an n*n matrix over F that has characteristic polynomial c(x) and minimal polynomial m(x)?

I was thinking it wouldnt be so if c(x) was not monic, and F[x] is a field of integers. Am I missing something, and how should the proof(or counterexample) go?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think the answer is yes (leaving aside trivialities like being monic). You can build the matrix by blocks (one big block per irreducible factor and then smaller blocks for the multiplicity of the factor in the characteristic).